# document.write is not working unless the window is manually focused

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using the following javascript to open a new window, focus on it, center it conpared to the window source, then write in a preset string which includes HTML markdown.

```
if (prodidarray.length > 0 && upgradebox.checked == true) {
    var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;  
    var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;  

    width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;  
    height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;  

    var left = ((width / 2) - (300 / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;  
    var top = ((height / 2) - (200 / 2)) + dualScreenTop;  
    var alertWindow = window.open('','alertWindow', 'scrollbars=yes, width=300, height=200, top=' + top + ', left=' + left);  

// Puts focus on the newWindow  
    if (window.focus) {  
        alertWindow.focus();  
    }  

    alertWindow.document.write(prodidalertstring);
    alertWindow.document.close();
}
```

However when I do this, while it does pop up the window, focus on it, and position it properly, it does not write the string. The HTML of the about/blank page is just HTML and Body, with no other content.

That is, unless I leave the failed blank window open, and click on it when i run the script that should open the window in the first place. In this situation, a new window is not opened, and the string writes into the already open window successfully.

For reference, the **prodidalertstring** outputs perfectly into the console, here is a paraphrased version that includes all the key elements.

```
var prodidalertstring = "<p>An example popup filler" + "<br>" + withAString + "</p>";
```

For context this is being used in a chrome browser extension, so it does not need to be cross platform. This issue only started recently, and was working fine a few months ago, so I feel like it might be an issue with the new chrome update. I have tried numerous other ways to code this, including DOM elements, but to no avail.

Comment: if window content is not big then you can simply use data urls like this: `data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<a%20href%3D%27test.com%27>test<%2Fa>`

Comment: Try calling `alertWindow.focus()` at the end. Removing focus from the current window is probably suspending its JavaScript.